# -[UIView setShowsFPS:]: unrecognized selector error

Tags: uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboard, viewcontroller

I need to open a ViewController when a UIButton was press , for doing that I use the following 
code :

```
NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

when it take the final line

```
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

it give me the following error:

> -[UIView setShowsFPS:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9bd5610 2013-07-16 14:40:52.728 ChainZoo[3026:a0b] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[UIView setShowsFPS:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x9bd5610'

Anyone knows the error?
thanks in advance!!

Comment: Well, you're calling a `setShowFPS` method for a UIView, and UIView doesn't know this method...
Does your next VC has a method called setShowFPS?

Comment: no it didn´t... There is no setShowFPS method

Comment: What class is your next VC? Do you use ZBar ?

Comment: No, it is just a scroll view with an image inside.

Answer (score 7):

On the **storyborad**, select your **ViewController's view** and click "**Show the identity inspector**" (third little tab on the top right side).

You'll see Custom Class textview.

Write "**SKView**" and try to run again.

You should init your VC's view as a SKView.